# how to debug javascript embedded in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to debug java-script or j-query embedded in the same view of razor page in google chrome

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.DoSomeStuff();
    });
</script>
}
```

how to debug and put break point in google chrome. because i cannot find script in source tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add the word **debugger** into your code ? maybe it can help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    debugger
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.DoSomeStuff();
});
```

Comment: Reference to [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

Answer (score 1):

In chrome dev tools there is a debug tool.

1. Go to Dev Tools (F12)
2. Go to the sources tab
3. Choose the file you want to debug
4. Choose breaking points, like this:
   [image]
5. Press on F5 to start the debug mode.
6. Press on F10 to see each interaction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, script file is in **localhost/scripts/app.min.js** but it is minified (compressed) so after selecting curly brackets at the left bottom you can pretty print that script file and put break points.